# Mad Mechanic makes motorcycle fly through mountain?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for an 80’s movie. I only saw one scene briefly in passing at a friends house as late as 1987.

A mad scientist charachter was seated, working in a garage that opened up to a high desert scene.  There was some sort of vehicle he was working on, a motocycle or low profile car of some kind which seemed to contain a human being, perhaps a child or adult.  My friend who’s house I was visiting described the person in the vehicle as one of the mad scientist’s relatives.  As he was wrapping up preparations for launch he kissed the exposed skin/cheek/thigh of the person inside the vehicle.

My memory gets fuzzy beyond that but I think the scientist then launched the vehicle into the distant mountain where it phased through the matter similar to Buckaroo Bonzai’s car.  Not sure if I’m conflating the two films though.

Comment: Take a look at the [Circuitry Man (1990)](https://youtu.be/bcw4LtLa4s4?t=75). There are some strange cars and a jump through the wall (but it is hologram actually).